# Samsung Kies restore a backup from another PC

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, samsung-kies, restore

I recently did a backup as I had to send my S3 to samsung to fix a broken screen. I took my backup on my work pc and copied the whole backup folder to an external drive. I now have my phone back and copied the folder to my home pc.

Kies is not finding the backups. Is there a way I can backup from this pc with a backup taken from somewhere else?

**EDIT**
Just realised that kies might be looking for *.sbu files. But I cannot a recent one there.

BUT, there's a folder named GT-I9300_20130225014623, it has all the files from my last backup with *.bk extensions. These are all recent, and I can see .apk files too.